# Django: tracking down DjangoUnicodeDecodeError error

Tags: python, django, unicode

While attempting to render a template I'm getting the following error:

```
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 26-27: invalid data. You passed in '\xce\x88\xce\xbe\xce\xbf\xce\xb4\xce\xb1 \xcf\x83\xcf\x84\xce\xb7\xce\xbd \xce\xb5\xcf\x81\xce\xb3\xce...' (<type 'str'>)
```

The template is fairly large and complex, so I'm hoping for some tips on how to track down where exactly this is coming from.

A few facts that might be helpful:

- The template is generally unicode friendly; we display a fair amount of unicode data through it
- The mysql table the data is coming from has utf8 encoding
- **This is a strange one**: The error doesn't show up on my staging server when using the same code base and the same production data. The setup is very similar to the production server: Python 2.5.1, Django-1.1.1, mysql 5.0.38, ubuntu.

I'm not sure where exactly to look for the badly encoded data, any hints or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere you're truncating a string, but you're doing it on a `str` instead of a `unicode` so you end up splitting a UTF-8 character sequence in half. Always perform text operations on `unicode`, never `str`.

Comment: Aaah, excellent suggestion, will try it when I get back in front of the computer.

Comment: Ignacio was dead on. I'd written a tag to truncate titles and had used str() instead of unicode() to convert the tag parameters to strings. Switched it over to unicode() and the problems went away.

Comment: This just bit me too. Should we then ever again use str()?

Answer (score 1):

What is reported by the exception is 26 bytes of valid UTF-8 followed by `'\xce...'`

It looks very much to me that some piece of software, either in your code or in Django's code is doing something like this:

```
def too_big_display(strg, maxlen):
    return strg[:maxlen-3] + "..."
```

and in your case calling it with `too_big_display(your_Greek_text_encoded_in_utf8,30)`

and so you are seeing a **secondary error** ... `\xce.` is not valid UTF-8.

I suggest that you look very carefully through the **traceback** (*which you should have shown us, and still can, by editing your question*) to see whether there is any evidence of a primary error. If not, scrutinise your code for such a truncation.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody has similar situation like mine: 
I recently changed a MySQL table to use collation utf8_bin and ran into the same problem. I found out that in staging I have MySQL-python 1.2.3. Upgrading to 1.2.4 solved the problem for me. I am using python2.7, Django1.4.2.